# Is there an IESG standard for specifying structured data with URL query strings?

Tags: php, url, query-string, rfc

### Context

This post assumes the following context:

- Internet Engineering Steering Group (IESG) standards and RFCs
- URL query strings specifying structured (non-scalar) datatypes

### Problem

PHP seems to have a convention for specifying structured datatypes in a URL query string, but Trevor wishes to know if this convention is specified anywhere by the IESG, or any other standards body.

#### Details

The following example of the PHP `parse_str` function demonstrates how to specify a PHP array using a special notation in a URL query string:

```
  $str = "alpha=one&arr[]=bravo+charlie&arr[]=delta";

  parse_str($str, $output);
  echo $output['alpha'];  // one
  echo $output['arr'][0]; // bravo charlie
  echo $output['arr'][1]; // delta
```

In the above example, PHP automatically creates a sturctured data element (an array) simply by virtue of the syntax in the URL query string.

This is useful, because it allows an application programmer to parse URL query name-value pairs in such a way that permits the automatic creation of arrays.

The problem is, Trevor cannot locate any specification for this convention, or whether this is a language-specific feature of PHP.

### Questions

- Is there an IESG-endorsed specification for this specific convention?
- If no to above, are there any documented conventions for specifying structured data in a query string for other programming languages?

Comment: This isn't a PHP-specific URL query string, but a mapping of a URL query string to PHP datatypes. Different languages will map that URL query string to their own appropriate datatypes

Comment: I'd also like Trevor to know that this particular syntax
isn't unique to PHP anymore (RoR does it too).
It just originated as decorative feature and implementation
kludge here. IRI/URL schemes allow and assume 
[list-style values](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6570#section-3.2.8) by just specifying multiple parameters with the same
identifier.

Comment: @MarkBaker **//This isn't a PHP-specific URL query string//** that's the rationale for asking the question. **//Different languages will map that URL query string to their own appropriate datatypes//** that much is easily understood. The question is whether each language implements its own ad-hoc convention for mapping query strings to native objects, or whether language designers have a specification they can follow.

Comment: Why does there need to be a standard? PHP approaches variables in this way different from many other languages in that `foo=1&foo=2&...` does not form an array but silently overwrites the same variable, so you need to specify `foo[]=1&...` . This behaviour seems to indicate there is no set rules for query string interpretations but rules based on how the receiving language is structured itself .

Comment: "Why does there need to be a standard?" If we assume passing structured data in a query string is a useful thing to do, the benefits of standardizing the format seem glaringly obvious. In a word, interoperability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RFC for Uniform Resource Identifiers ([RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)) does not specify anything other than name-value pairs for the query string. Section [3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) is the relevant section, but I have read the whole document and cannot recall mention of what you are referring to. I believe it is purely convention adopted by language implementors.